# Why does SE say I've raised two types of flags?

Tags: discussion, support

I flagged [this question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/83233/how-do-i-use-tilt-sensor) for being off-topic (app development) when I was working through one of the queues. When I was browsing later, I looked at the question again and started to flag it, when I saw that I had already done so.

However, the SE system had two flag options grayed out instead of just one. I know I definitely did not mark this question as a duplicate. I even checked my "raised flags" page to make sure.

Is this a bug? Or is there some other reason why the system thinks I've flagged the question twice for two different reasons?

[image: Screenshot of two raised flags]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All the close reasons count as one "type of flag" for this purpose. If you've VTC'ed or flagged with a close reason, you can't VTC or flag again with a close reason, even if it's a different reason.

The spam and offensive flags work in the same way: if you've flagged as spam, you can't also flag as offensive, but you can still VTC or flag with a close reason.

Comment: Interesting. Is there a list of the 'types' of flags there are? Or is it simply those 3 (spam, VTC, moderator)? And why isn't "it is very low quality" considered a VTC?

Comment: I don't think there's a specific list: it matches the review/moderation queue that the flagged post will go into. You can only add a post once to each review queue. Very low quality is separate because it has its own queue.